# pinvoke c#: how can i map "const char **output"?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling, com-interop

i have a C function with this prototype:

```
void foo(const char **output);
```

i compiled C file into a DLL and a i make DllImport("my.dll");

but how should i write c# prototype?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This could mean multiple things.  Show a snippet that demonstrates how foo() is using the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be a Pointer to byte array:

```
 private static extern void foo(IntPtr pointerToByteArray);
```

Usage:

```
        fixed(byte* buffer = new byte[LENGTH_WHICH_YOU_KNOW_IS_ENOUGH])
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(buffer);
            foo(ptr);
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works!
i used follow code to recovery value of the string:

IntPtr nestedPtr= Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr);
string value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(nestedPtr);

Comment: You can avoid the 'unsafe' `fixed (byte*` by using `IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(LENGTH_WHICH_YOU_KNOW_IS_ENOUGH);`

Comment: Don't forget to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)` after calling foo and extracting the string (use a finally clause).